# FTP commands missing or misbehaving with Filezilla Server on Windows

Tags: ftp

We are using FileZilla as an FTP server in Windows machines (Win 7, Win 2008), and I notice that it is missing some FTP commands. In particular I miss the "TYPE I" command, because some of the our applications use Apache Commons NET FTPClient, which uses TYPE I and not BINARY.

Any idea why is that?

```
220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.39 beta written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de) Please visit http://sourceforge.
User (62.90.217.2:(none)): 
331 Password required for 
Password:
230 Logged on
ftp> ?
Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:

!               delete          literal         prompt          send
?               debug           ls              put             status
append          dir             mdelete         pwd             trace
ascii           disconnect      mdir            quit            type
bell            get             mget            quote           user
binary          glob            mkdir           recv            verbose
bye             hash            mls             remotehelp
cd              help            mput            rename
close           lcd             open            rmdir
ftp> type I
I: unknown mode.
```

Comment: As this relates to a design decision wouldn't you be betterasking  this on the filezilla form http://forum.filezilla-project.org/ ?

Comment: @Iain. you're probably right. I just don't like forums very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

The question is confusing. You mention Apache Commons NET FTPClient but the example posted looks like a good old-fashioned BSD /usr/bin/ftp. The help lists "binary" as an available command.

It also has a "type" command, but you used it incorrectly. The "type I" that was entered at the ftp client prompt is not sent directly to the server (use `quote TYPE I` for that). The BSD ftp client's "type" command accepts arguments "ascii", "binary", "image", "ebcdic", "tenex". If you say `type binary` or `type image` it will send `TYPE I` to the server, exactly the same thing it would do if you said `binary`. (Try doing a `debug` first if you're not convinced.) When you say `type I` it doesn't know what you're talking about.

The example you've given doesn't prove anything about the server because it never sent a `TYPE` command to the server.